# Deleting data from a mockapi.io json, with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, mocking

I am using mockapi.io for my first big learning project(ecomerce) and i can do get, post but seems like not delete. It deletes the row in the admin page table but not the product from the online api. Seems impossible to find info about this issue online, or i just don't know how to ask the right question. Maybe it's not even posible to really delete from a mock api?!

I am geting in the console: http.js:21 DELETE https://6060b8b904b05d0017ba2dfb.mockapi.io/products?id=50 400 (Bad Request)
So it does compose the right link to that specific product, but just doesn't delete it.

```
function deleteProduct(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
   const id = e.target.id;
   e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove(id);
   const productToDelete = `https://6060b8b904b05d0017ba2dfb.mockapi.io/products?id=${id}`;
   http
  .delete(productToDelete)
  .then((data) => getProductsAdmin())
  .catch("Error on delete!");
 }
}
```

Let me know if you need printscreens or more code. Thanks

Comment: Alternatively you can try https://themockapis.in/.

Answer (score 1):

the answer above is correct, and finding info about mockapi.io on the internet was hard for me so, I just wanted to answer to the related problems with mockapi.io when deleting a specific object from DB.

When adding new objects to the resource mockapi.io assigns an id to them. And when you want to delete that new object you should make a request(`/products/${id}`) to that assigned id, but the problem is if you have your own id in the object and mockapi.io assigns another id to this object when adding it to the resource, your request will address different object.

I solved it this way:

First, you change the name of the id that mockapi.io assigns automatically
For example, I changed it to "index"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6zY2.png

```
const { data } = axios.get(`https://UNIQUE_PROJECT.mockapi.io/cart?id=${thisCard.id}`);
await axios.delete(`https://UNIQUE_PROJECT.mockapi.io/cart/${data[0].index}`);
```

It finds an object with my assigned id, then I make a delete request with index(the id that mockapi.io assigns automatically to new objects).

> Important to remember, a delete request(`/cart/${id}`) works only with identifiers (id, index, etc.) that mockapi.io assigns itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think your parameter's link was wrong, it should be :

```
https://6060b8b904b05d0017ba2dfb.mockapi.io/products/${id}
```